# Cannot enter a forward slash character when logging in via ssh

Tags: bash, terminal, readline

When I `ssh` into one of our servers, I cannot enter a forward slash character, which makes it difficult to do pretty much anything (like `ls /`).  **How can I get the forward slash to work?**

Some additional information:

- `/etc/issue` claims it's running "CentOS release 5.7 (Final)"
- The only way I know this is by running `ssh me@some-host cat /etc/issue`
- I'm using Mac OS X Terminal.app, and I've never had trouble with this, on Centos 5 systems or otherwise
- I don't know who or how the machine was built and set up
- `echo $TERM` reports `xterm-256color`
- i don't know if this makes sense to anyone (it doesn't make sense to me), but i `diff`'ed the `/etc/inputrc` of the malfunctioning server with one that works and got the following:

  ```
  $ diff /tmp/{good,bad}_inputrc
  1c1
  < # do not bell on tab-completion
  ---
  > /# do not bell on tab-completion
  37a38,49
  > 
  > # Home Key
  > "\e[7~":beginning-of-line
  > 
  > # End Key
  > "\e[8~":end-of-line
  > 
  > # Delete Key
  > "\e[3~":delete-char
  > 
  > # Insert Key
  > "\e[2~":paste-from-clipboard
  ```

Comment: If you press `ctrl + v` then `/`, does it work?

Comment: yes, that does work

Answer (score 7):

This line is your problem

```
/# do not bell on tab-completion
```

If I add that line to my working config, slash stops working.

The only clue that I can find about this is in the readline man page:

> Blank lines are ignored.  Lines beginning with a # are
>          comments.  Lines beginning with a $ indicate conditional constructs.  Other lines denote key bindings and variable settings.

Since it's not a blank line, and doesn't begin with `#` or `$`, it must be being treated as a key binding.

Comment: Nice catch. Completely missed that :-)

Answer (score 0):

A program called xmodmap can be used to modify keymaps. See `man xmodmap` if it's already installed.

In a nutshell, use `xev` to see details about X events. Fire that up, and strike your / key. On my setup this is the result I get:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4e00001,
root 0x15a, subw 0x0, time 107752919, (784,828), root:(789,850),
state 0x10, keycode 61 (keysym 0x2f, slash), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2f) "/"
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Then, on the remote machine, use `xmodmap -e 'keycode [KEYCODE] = [KEYSYM]` to create the mapping, where [KEYCODE] and [KEYSYM] are the values retrieved from xev. Try setting the default 61,0x2f first to see if it just needs to be reset. (i.e., `xmodmap -e 'keycode 61 = 0x2f'`)

If that's a no-go, try mapping a different key. For example, I tried keycode 105 (right control) to 0x2f. That worked locally and in an ssh session for me.

Edit:

You may also want to set the question mark. Extend the previous command to `xmodmap -e 'keycode 61 = 0x2f 0x3f`'. You can see a complete [list of keysyms here](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/List_of_Keysyms_Recognised_by_Xmodmap).

Comment: xmodmap doesn't matter here, as X is not being used.